# detecting the position of an error

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, information-theory, coding-theory

I am looking for code that detect an error and it's position (or an aproximation of it), this is more than an error detector code but a little less than a correcting code.

Do you know something like this or some literature that I can check?

Comment: I'd look into the [7,4] Hamming code.

Comment: See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/98933/15503) for some discussion. What kind of an application do you have in mind (that can make use of "approximate location of an error")? If computer memory, IIRC Fujiwara is the researcher you want to study.

Comment: If we leave aside the "approximation": to "detect an error and its position" is the same as correcting it, no ?